# Should I Accept this answer?

Tags: discussion

I got [an excellent Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/211532/is-there-anything-like-jigdo/221262#221262), but considering that the suggestion given doesn't exactly match what I was asking for, should I accept it. I'm asking here because the main Question (*Is there anything like jigdo?*) was actually answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The bottom line is:

Do *you* think it provides the answer *you* wanted?

I get the feeling the answer here is no, otherwise you wouldn't be here.

### What to do

#### Assuming my last statement was correct

*Don't* accept the answer if you're not happy with it.

But, what I'd suggest you should do is edit the question so it asks the question you really want answered (presumably: is there anything *GUI based* that is like jigdo). You only imply this secondary requirement in the questions current form, so rework the question so this requirement is clearly a requirement - hopefully either this user (or another) will provide an answer that really does solve your problem.

#### Bounty

Obviously, as a further issue, you currently have a live bounty on the question.

If you do nothing **half** the value will automatically be awarded to the highest scoring answer (of at least +2) that was made after the bounty opened, the excess half is lost forever.

But, you can award the bounty to an answer *without* accepting it, so you can do this if you wish to reward the answer without accepting it. But, I'd recommend a quick comment on the answer explaining why you did this to avoid causing confusion.

---

### General Note

If you're not entirely happy with the given answers (on any question you ask), don't feel compelled to accept an answer! It's fine to leave the question open (but don't leave too many open, please accept whenever it's appropriate).

This has the advantage that in the future others might find and answer your question (but may be put off if you've accepted something already).